# Screen rendering problems after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 I'm suffering severe rendering issues in unity:

- Some parts of any application (for instance Firefox, or emacs, etc) are blank, or are not rendered, or are blinking.
- Some fonts in an application are not correct rendered, maybe only some part ([see Eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNERk.png)).
- There is some shadows in desktop background.

It's something that occurs from time to time (it's works great for hours and suddenly start to give this rendering problems).

I was trying to find a bug in launchpad but without success.

My card (using i915 module):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0042] (rev 02)
```

I've tried to reset compiz/unity or gnome but does not help.

Any tip?

**Update**: [A Firefox screenshot of how my profile in Ask Ubuntu looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Qay.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).